# How to programmatically add a paragraph item to a user account?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I already added the *Check in/out History* field to the user account, which has the *check-in date* and *check-out date* fields.

How can I programmatically add new items to *Check in/out History*?

I need to create some history for users.

| Check-in date | Check-out date |
| --- | --- |
| 04/05/21 | 05/07/21 |
| 03/05/20 | 04/14/20 |

Comment: Quite broad the question. What have you tried so far? Did you check for "programmatically create paragraph items" or similar? User entity is just another fieldable entity. Same as nodes. Most answers you'll find are for nodes. You just need to replace the node object with an user object then, done. When and where do you want to update the users? API call? Some hook that gets triggered in a particular situation?

Comment: for example I have field_history as paragraph in user account, and there are 2 fields in paragraph field_checkin_date, field_checkout_date, and I want on some action add new paragraph items, what should be my steps?
1. how reach paragraph field for user?
2. how add new paragraph item with 2 sub fields?
3. how append new item to paragraph?

Comment: Thanks to all, this code solve my task:

Comment: $paragraph = Paragraph::create(['type' => 'checkin_history', 'field_checkin' => $checkin_date,  'field_checkout' => format_date(time(), 'html_date')]);
$paragraph->save(); 

$current = $account->get('field_check_in_out_history')->getValue();
$current[] = array(
   'target_id' => $paragraph->id(),
   'target_revision_id' => $paragraph->getRevisionId(),
);
  
$account->set('field_check_in_out_history', $current);
$account->save();

Comment: where:
//field_check_in_out_history  -> field in user account
//checkin_history -> paragraph type
// field_checkin and field_checkout paragraph fields

Comment: Please update the question for clarification and to add details, please don't use comments for that. Next reader should get all relevant info at one glance.

Comment: And then please add an answer with your solution, and accept it, to help future readers to get the solution at one glance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to achieve the task using the following code.

```php
$paragraph = Paragraph::create([
  'type' => 'checkin_history',
  'field_checkin' => $checkin_date,
  'field_checkout' => format_date(time(), 'html_date')
]); 
$paragraph->save(); 

$current = $account->get('field_check_in_out_history')->getValue(); $current[] = [
  'target_id' => $paragraph->id(),
  'target_revision_id' => $paragraph->getRevisionId(),
]; 

$account->set('field_check_in_out_history', $current); 
$account->save();
```

- *field_check_in_out_history* is the user account field
- *checkin_history* is the paragraph type
- *field_checkin* and *field_checkout* are paragraph fields